# How to change these UIs in iOS to Mac OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I want change some codes from iOS to Mac OS X, can anyone give me some tips

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( width , height ));
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,width, height)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and

```
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

and

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.75);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [NSGraphicsContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html).